# How to change Window phone 7 Profile by code or API

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Is there an API for WP7 which can let us access its system Profile i.e Silent, Meeting, Loud etc .
i am creating an app which will access the phone profile and change it according to the environment of the user.

I just want to know the API which can help me do this work or does WP7 supports this function

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think WP7 supports this. The most you could do is change the volume, which MIGHT automatically set it to vibrate (if it's at 0)

Answer (score 1):

In the current release of the SDK, there is no way you can access these capabilities. As with other system functions, I am sure there is a native hook, but it is not exposed in the current release. Chances are it will be available in Mango (the SDK will be released later this year).

Comment: ! you sure in the coming sdk this functionality will be available to us ? can you share the link from where youread that?

Comment: There is no guarantee it will be in the new SDK. I saw what was shown at MIX and I am sure that the new SDK will offer more access to the system itself.